# Laravel 5.2 hasManyThrough relationship issue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 3 tables: orders, codes, events

I want to be able to pull all events that an order has, but there's an intermediary table that acts as a pivot table. I've been trying to use `hasManyThrough` and `belongsToMany` (along with `withPivot`) without any luck.

Examples:

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('events'); // tried this, fails
    return $this->hasManyThrough('events', 'codes'); // tried this, fails
    return $this->hasManyThrough('events', 'codes', 'event_id', 'id'); // tried this, fails
}
```

Any pointers would be great!

[image: example image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a [`belongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) setup. First, the first parameter is the name of the related class. Second, since your pivot table doesn't follow the Laravel naming conventions, you need to specify the name of the pivot table in your relationship definition:

```
public function events()
{
    // first parameter is the name of the related class
    // second parameter is pivot table name
    return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class, 'codes');
}
```

With this setup, you can do:

```
// get an order
$order = Order::first();

// has all the events related to an order
$events = $order->events;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. I will show a one you can get it done.

In `Order.php` model

```
public function codes(){
   return $this->has('App\Http\Code');
}
```

In `Code.php` model

```
public function orders(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Order');
}

public function events(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Event');
}
```

In `Event.php` model

```
public function codes(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Code');
}
```

Then in you Controller, call them to get required data.

In your case you can do it like below:

```
$orders = Order::with(['codes' => function($q){
    $q->with('events');
})->get();
```

May be you can get them with nested manner(not sure about this because i didn't tried before posting):

`$orders = Order::with('codes.events')->get();`

put `return $orders;` in your controller to see the query.

Enjoy!